# Десятичные числа MS ACCESS C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, double, oledb

Суть в том, что у меня в базе данных есть как даты, так и десятичные числа. Однако, при записывании в запрос числа с запятой он крашится с данным сообщением:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Не совпадает число значений запроса и число результирующих полей.
```

Запрос:

```
Order = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Abiturients ( Institut_Code, Abiturient_Code, Lastname, Gender, Birthdate, Average_Score)" +            // SQL-запрос - вставить полученные
                " VALUES ('" + Icode + "', '" + Acode + "', '" + Lname + "', '"+ Gender +"', '"+ Bdate +"', "+ Average_Score +")", Connection);
```

Всё, соответственно, string, кроме Average_Score.
Сам Average_Score получается из

```
Average_Score = double.Parse(textbox1.Text)
```

Попытался поменять среду исполнения (или как оно там зовётся) с русской на английскую - меняется дата, и запрос выдаёт ошибку о нарушении соответствия данных.
Уважаемые знатоки, спасите.

Comment: Спокойствие. Сейчас мы угадаем, какой у Вас запрос и как Вы вставляете туда данные.

Comment: Я поглядел в хрустальный шар, он показал ошибку в строке 123.

Comment: Дополнил, уважаемые знатоки.

Comment: Не валяйте дурака и используйте параметризованные запросы. Следующей у Вас вылезет ошибка с датой.

Comment: Неужели через параметры игнорируется несоответствие точки и запятой?

Comment: "через параметры" десятичный разделитель вообще не имеет значения. Конечно, если параметр - число, а не строка.

Comment: Всё гениальое - просто, действительно.
Премного благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Как верно указали выше, лучше использовать параметризованные запросы. Однако, это не всегда возможно (например, когда запрос собирается по частям с учетом разных учловий - не только значения проверок, но и их наличие).

Для понимания сути проблемы, нужно понимать, каким образом данные преобразуются в текстовый вид. Выведите на печать значения, которые вызывают ошибки и проверьте их формат. MS Access очень привередлив в этом плане.

1. **Числа с плавающей точкой** должны иметь разделителем ***точку***, а не запятую (в этом случае sql-движок считает, что переданы два целых числа, а не одно с плавающей точкой). (примеры на псевдокоде на основе python)

```py
# не правильно
>>> sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE score = ' + str(score) + ';'
'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE score = 12,3;'

# правильно
>>> str_score = str(score).replace(',', '.')
>>> sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE score = ' + str_score + ';'
'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE score = 12.3;'
```

2. **Даты** должны быть строго ***в формате USA-date***, а именно `#M/D/YYYY#`. Отмечу, что разделитель должен быть именно `/`, а не точка или пробел. Порядок указания месяца и дня так же важны. Сперва указывается месяц, затем день. При этом числа должны быть в односимвольном формате (вместо `01-31` для дней и `01-12` для месяца должно быть указано `1-31` и `1-12` соответственно). Дата с обоих сторон заключается в решетку `#`.

```py
# не правильно
>>> sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE bdate = ' + str(bdate) + ';'
'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE bdate = 14.11.2019;'

# правильно
>>> d, m, y = splitdate(bdate)
>>> sqlstr = f'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE bdate = #{m}/{d}/{y}#;'
'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE bdate = #11/14/2019#;'
```

Answer (score 0):

... используйте параметризованные запросы. Следующей у Вас вылезет ошибка с датой.

"через параметры" десятичный разделитель вообще не имеет значения. Конечно, если параметр - число, а не строка.